# DataGridView RowValidation Error

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I'm sync my data from Grid to DataBase using really weird way :

for example :

```
#region Line methods
private void LinesView_UserDeletedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    lineTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.Line);
}

private void LinesView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    lineTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.Line);
}

private void LinesView_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    lineTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.Line);
}
#endregion
```

but when I switched some columns to ComboBox I need to make some trick before Update alike that :

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //deltaTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.Delta); TODO
}

private void dataGridView1_UserDeletedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    deltaTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.Delta);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (lambdacat != null)
    {
        string selected = (LimView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).FormattedValue.ToString();
        if (selected != "")
        {
            int find = Array.IndexOf(dict, dict.Where(x => x == selected).FirstOrDefault());
            LimView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = dictiddarray[find];
            //deltaTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.Delta);
        }
    }
    //deltaTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.Delta);
}
```

troubles comes after uncommenting Update method.

When I opening the window with a table I've got error message : **Damaged the internal index DataTable: "5. "** How can I fix / avoid this error ?

Comment: I can't help but notice that you're using the FormattedValue property, and I'm wondering whether using LimView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text might avoid it... although I do suspect you've already tried this and got the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does modifying it to this work ?

```
 if (selected != "")
    {
        int find = Array.IndexOf(dict, dict.Where(x => x == selected).FirstOrDefault());
        LimView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = dictiddarray[find];
         fRIIBDataSet.Delta.BeginInit(); //
         deltaTableAdapter.Update(fRIIBDataSet.Delta);
         fRIIBDataSet.Delta.EndInit();
    }
```

Comment: Not , same Error. Damaged the internal index DataTable: "5. "

Comment: Are there multiple tables in your dataset, or specific table wherein the records are getting updated then **fRIIBDataSet.Delta.Tables["tablename"].BeginLoadData()** and **fRIIBDataSet.Delta.Tables["tablename"].BeginLoadData()**

Comment: @V4Vendetta I'm not sure what do you mean. But I want to sync only one table and it works without comboboxes.

Comment: No i mean the Data is being modified and probably its in use maybe bound to the grid or being updated/used by some other thread

Comment: yes , I think this ( LimView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = dictiddarray[find] ) is updating data. But I can't ignore it.

Comment: I don't think adding **BeginLoadData()** and **EndLoadData()** will ignore that .. it will allow you to modify the record.Please check by adding that

Comment: good to know ... hope it doesn't break anything (don't think so but you would know it better)

Comment: got strange error on Update then : Concurrency violation: UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

Comment: has that row been deleted ? or i believe you need **AcceptChanges** on the table

Comment: another trouble is my Cell[0] invisible so I can't just edit it this way (seems like)

Comment: moved Cell[0] Update to private void LimView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) method. Fixed. Thank you for helping.